# Can i use appframework and jquery mobile in a phonegap project?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, appframework

I want to use a framework to develope in phonegap, i used jquery mobile for mobile web development but now i have performance problems with it. For example in android 2.3 the transitions efects are not working and in greaters versions of android work but they are not smooth (I try it on a galaxy s4).
Recently saw the appframework and their transitions are smooth so i want to use it without losing jquery Mobile power.
Any suggestion?

Comment: try SENCHA framework.